# Extracting only some rows of a table in R

Tags: r

I have a table in this format:

[image: fragment of table]

I am trying to write a R script that will "extract" from the table for example the cases that have  c2==1, (c2 and c3)== 1, (c2 and c4)==1, (c1 and c2 and c3)==1, and so on ... 
so that in the end I will have a list that has the Counts value for each case.

Example list for columns that have c2 == 1:
C2<-c(4, 42, 12, ...)

I tried to it on this way: totalC2<-table[table[c1]], also if I use table$c1 == 1  it is not working.

Can anyone give-me a suggestion how to solve this problem?

I forgot to mention that the table comes from the function:
vennCounts()

Comment: If I correctly understood the question, there is a misprint in `c2 == 1 like C2 <- c(4, 42, 12, ...)`, it should be `c2 == 1 like C2 <- c(5, 42, 12, ...)` regarding the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output you will have named list with corresponding counts. But maybe the same results could be achieved with the more clear and straightforward solution. Let's wait and see for another answers.

```
# data simulation
c1 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=T)
c2 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=T)
c3 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=T)
c4 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=T)
Counts <- sample(1:100, 10)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2,c3, c4, Counts)

f <- function(y) {
  idx <- apply(df[,y, drop=F], 1, function(x) all(x == 1))
  df[idx, "Counts"]
}

out <- list()
l <- sapply(1:4, function(x) {combn(x=c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"), m=x, simplify=F)})
l <- unlist(l, recursive=F)
for (x in l) {
  out[[paste(x, collapse="")]] <- f(x)
}
```

Comment: I cannot convert my table to data frame, because is got that table by using the function vennCounts

Comment: Does this code produce an error for your data? I'm not familiar with bioconductor package. But why you cannot convert this table to matrix or data.frame? You receive error message during conversion?

Comment: yes, i get an error: "   cannot coerce class '"VennCounts"' into a data.frame "

Comment: And you cannot convert it to the matrix object, too? Then probably you should wait someone who is familiar with this package.

Comment: @Leo.peis, than you can convert your data to matrix and run given example of code, it should work correctly with matrix too.